# Who can absorb the Genki Dama?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-movies

In the Dragonball Movie, Super Android 13 Goku absorbs the Genki Dama to become more powerful and defeat his rival. Apparently (not sure), something similar could happen in Dragon Ball Super for a preview from the following episodes which was released.

That leads me to the question, who can absorb the Genki Dama? Is only the creator the Genki Dama who can absorb it? Or can someone else with good ki absorb it too?

We've seen in the first Genki Dama Goku made that someone with good spirit like Gohan could bounce the Genki Dama, may be someone with good ki can absorb it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far there has been no reference to another person who can absorb the Genki Dama other than the creator, which happens accidentally in the latest Dragon Ball Super episode. Hypothetically speaking, I don't think a person with good ki can absorb it, although they aren't harmed, A Genki Dama Bomb is still an attack used to defeat foes who's ki isn't 'good', So it is safe to assume that Goku will only use it against people he knows it'll harm. Having someone with good ki absorb it would most probably make them OP so it is probable that it is introduced later in order to defeat a strong character.